# How to get data when it is in a JSONObject in the position [0] of a JSONArray?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am trying that my app send two parameters to PHP file, where that file get data from mySQL database and send back to my app an array with the data.

Everything works but the problem is that I cannot get every row of the response separately because the data is a JSONObject in the position [0] of a JSONArray. I have tried a loop FOR, but it takes the values of the first registry in every iteration and it cannot reach the next.

I have tried every related post in here and I cannot solve it. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

This the code I have in my android app:

```
private void llamadovolley() {

        final String userPlayer = etUser.getText().toString();
        final String passwordPlayer = etPassword.getText().toString();
        String url = "http://192.168.1.129/studyBonusGame/3CheckUserNew.php";

        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject playerJson=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    d.deleteTables();
                    

                    for(int i=0;i<playerJson.length();i++)
                    {

                        ObjectPlayer player = new ObjectPlayer();

                        player.setPlayerName(playerJson.getString("NOM_JUG"));
                        player.setPlayerVirtualDate(playerJson.getString("VIRT_DATE"));
                        player.setAccountMoney(playerJson.getDouble("ACCOUNT_MONEY"));
                        player.setWeekTournamentMode(playerJson.getInt("WEEK_TOURNAMENT_MODE"));
                        player.setWeekTournamentRound(playerJson.getInt("WEEK_TOURNAMENT_ROUND"));
                        player.setButtonFinancesEnabled(playerJson.getInt("BUTTON_FINANCES_ENABLED"));
                        player.setButtonQAManagerEnabled(playerJson.getInt("BUTTON_QAMANAGER_ENABLED"));
                        player.setButtonSuccessErrorGameEnabled(playerJson.getInt("BUTTON_SUCCESS_ERROR_GAME_ENABLED"));
                        player.setCurrentPack(playerJson.getString("CURRENT_PACK"));
                        player.setCorrectQueVirtualDate(playerJson.getInt("CORRECT_QUE_VIRT_DATE"));
                        player.setWeekTournamentLevel(playerJson.getInt("WEEK_TOURNAMENT_LEVEL"));
                        player.setTokenX2(playerJson.getInt("TOKEN_X2"));
                        player.setTokenX3(playerJson.getInt("TOKEN_X3"));
                        player.setLotteryTickets(playerJson.getDouble("LOTTERY_TICKETS"));
                        player.setCurrentLivingPlace(playerJson.getString("CURRENT_LIVING_PLACE"));
                        player.setTotalLifeScore(playerJson.getDouble("TOTAL_LIFE_SCORE"));
                        player.setMusicMenusOnOff(playerJson.getInt("MUSIC_MENUS_ON_OFF"));
                        player.setRandomMarket(playerJson.getInt("RANDOM_MARKET"));
                        player.setAfterPacksScreen(playerJson.getInt("AFTER_PACKS_SCREEN"));
                        player.setTextEditorQue(playerJson.getString("TEXT_EDITOR_QUE"));
                        player.setTextEditorAns(playerJson.getString("TEXT_EDITOR_ANS"));
                        player.setIdQuestion(playerJson.getInt("ID_QUESTION"));
                        player.setCoins(playerJson.getInt("COINS"));


                        d.importOnlinePlayersTable(player);


                    }
                    Toast.makeText(userPass2Activity.this, "Imported correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<>();
                params.put("userPlayer", userPlayer);
                params.put("passwordPlayer", passwordPlayer);

                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rq.add(sr);
    }
```

And this is the PHP, just in case it helps:

```
<?php

try{

      $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database" , "root", "");
      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql="SELECT * FROM table_players WHERE userPlayer= :userPlayer AND passwordPlayer= :passwordPlayer";

      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);


      $userPlayer  = $_POST['userPlayer'];
      $passwordPlayer   = $_POST['passwordPlayer'];


      $userPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($userPlayer));
      $passwordPlayer=htmlentities(addslashes($passwordPlayer));

      $resultado->bindValue(":userPlayer", $userPlayer);
      $resultado->bindValue(":passwordPlayer", $passwordPlayer);

      $resultado->execute();

      $res = $resultado -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $json = json_encode($res);

      echo $json;


}catch(Exception $e){
      die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Comment: `htmlentities(addslashes` this will damage your data. Why do you do that?

Comment: @Dharman I thought that it is a way to protect the database against SQL injection. Thank you for telling me, I will investigate it deeper

Comment: Prepared statements with `bindValue` are protecting you against SQL injection, but the best protection is to just understand what SQL injection is. You should never put PHP variables directly in SQL. You don't do it in your code, so you are safe.

Comment: However, you might have a different vulnerability. You are using `try-catch` and then you expose the error message to the user. Don't ever do that. Errors should be logged on server and never shown to users.

Comment: @Dharman Very useful information. I really appreciate it. I tried to make my code safe as possible, but I still have a lot to learn. Thank you for your help